# Question about classifying semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups, semidirect-product, frobenius-groups

I have in some notes, this statement:

Given $C_3\ltimes C_7$ we know that for $a\in C_3$ and $b\in C_7$, and some $k$:

$$aba^{-1}=b^k$$

$$k^3\equiv 1(7)$$

The reason given is that $a^3=1$. Unfortunately, I'm stuck on making the connection between that fact and the conclusion that $k^3\equiv 1(7)$. I'd be grateful for some clarification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Observe:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
aba^{-1}&=&b^k\\
a\left(aba^{-1}\right)a^{-1}&=&ab^ka^{-1}\\
a^2ba^{-2}&=&ab^ka^{-1}\\
&=& a b b b \cdots b a^{-1} \\
&=&ab\; \left(a^{-1}a\right)\; b \;\left(a^{-1}a\right)\;b \cdots b  \; \left(a^{-1}a\right)\;b a^{-1} \\
&=&\left(ab a^{-1} \right)\;\;\left(ab a^{-1} \right)\;\left(ab a^{-1} \right)\;\cdots \left(ab a^{-1} \right)\; \\
&=& \left(b^k\right)\left(b^k\right)\left(b^k\right)\cdots \left(b^k\right)\\
&=& \left(b^k\right)^k\\
&=& b^{k^2}\\
\end{eqnarray*}$$
You can see what will happen if we do it again: $a^3ba^{-3}=b^{k^3}$.  But since $a^3=a^{-3}=\operatorname{id}$, this gives us that $b^{k^3}=b$.  Since the order of $b$ is $7$, that means we can say that the exponents of left and right hand sides are congruent modulo $7$.  Thus, $$k^3 \equiv 1 \pmod 7$$

Comment: Thanks much. And now I'm not surprised it was eluding me!